# Batch file to copy 2 most recent files into another folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I've been looking on the web and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Before I begin I'm by no means an experienced command line user so please be gentle.

I need a batch file that will copy the two most recent files from one directory to the other, I then need the files that were in the destination folder to be removed which just leaves those two newest visible.

It's worth noting that I have tried the /d command (not including a date) however, this starts copying all files rather than those that are the most recent.

Please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit upside down.
It's a bit clumsy to first copy files to the destination and then delete all except the two new ones.

- You could evaluate the two files and remember the names ( in an array )
- delete **all** files in dest
- and finally copy the remembered files

Impertinently ***stealing*** npocmaka's code as a base:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "source=c:\source_folder"
set "target=c:\target"

PushD "%source%"
set "counter=0"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir "*.bak" /b /o:-d /t:w') do (
   set /a counter+=1
   Set Copy[!counter!]=copy "%%~fA" "%target%\"
   if !counter! equ 2 goto :break
)
:break
Del /Q "%target%\*"
For /L %%C in (1,1,%counter%) Do !Copy[%%C]!
PopD
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your feedback, I've just tried this code, the two older files in the destination folder delete however nothing copies across, instead I'm left with an error prompting: Environment variable Copy[target" not defined

This appears on two separate lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry there was a percent sign missing, Changed.

Comment: Hmm, this code just seems to delete the files from the destination folder and not replace it with the newer ones. Source is C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Backup and Destination is H:\ePay Backups. I'm not sure if this will help at all, the files that need to be transferred are .bak

Comment: Great that is working. I have a new problem now, the files that are automatically created from one of our backup systems have a filename of EFT_20173494058.bak (the numbers after EFT are random), this file is roughly 150MB. The second file it produces has a filename of EFT_Scheduler_20173494058.bak (again the numbers after Scheduler are random), this is roughly 2.5MB. Both of these EFT files are produced automatically on a daily basis however, the code you provided is only copying the EFT_Scheduler files which are on separate days and isn't quite what I'm after. Is there a reason for this? Ta

Comment: The selection of the files is based on `dir /o:-d /t:c` which means order by date time  descending and selects the creation date. You could try if your requirement `most recent` is better matched with last written `/t:w` See `Help Dir` or `Dir /?` in a cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "source=c:\source"
set "target=c"\target"

set "counter=0"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir "%source%" /b /o:-d /t:c /a:-d') do (
   set /a counter=counter+1
   echo "%%#"
   copy "%source%\%%#" "%target%" /Y
   if !counter! equ 2 goto :break

)
:break
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input :) Unfortunately after amending the code to include my source and destination folders it doesn't copy or delete. Do you have any further advice?

Comment: @Admaine  - I've edited my script. 1) there was a need to prepend the source directory in the copy command. 2) It is possible the dir command to list also directories so I filtered them out. I've tested this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is for copying latest 4 files existing in a folder:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Variables are A, B, C, D
DIR "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Writing Tool\sourcefolder\*.fileextension" /A:-D /O:-D /B /S > filelist.tmp
3<filelist.tmp (
  for %%a in (A B C D) do (
    set /p %%a=<&3
  )
)
del filelist.tmp
:: Newest File
copy "%A%" "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Writing Tool\destinationfolder" 
:: Second Newest File
copy "%B%" "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Writing Tool\destinationfolder" 
:: Thirst Newest File
copy "%C%" "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Writing Tool\destinationfolder" 
:: Fourth Newest File
copy "%D%" "C:\Users\singh\Desktop\Writing Tool\destinationfolder" 

TIMEOUT 4
```

Comment: ***Above script is for copying latest 4 files existing  in a folder***

Comment: The explanation should be added directly to the answer, not in the comments.  Note that you can edit the answer after posting.